# I have 2 hard drives on my laptop and want to install ubuntu on one of them

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10, 20.10

I just recently upgraded my laptop by placing a ssd on my laptop, now my laptop has a 500gb ssd and 1tb hdd with windows 10 on both of them. The hdd has 2 partition on it with windows on c. I want to format c and install ubuntu on it, is it possible and how do i do that?

Comment: If I were you I would install Ubuntu on SSD because it is fast than HDD. During installation of Ubuntu,  you can wipe off the Windows installation in your HDD using the disk partition utility tool that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: during the installation of ubuntu will I have the option of installing ubuntu on hdd while wiping of windows on it?

Comment: Yes! Ubuntu will detect both SSD and your HDD and ask you where you want to install the Ubuntu OS. If you choose to use the entire HDD, it will automatically wipe off Windows and configure the HDD for Ubuntu Linux file system and mount point for /root and paging

Comment: that is what I wanted to know, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Comment: You mention only two partitions, so is Windows in old BIOS boot mode using MBR partitions? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so most hardware now is UEFI. If UEFI hardware better to have all installs in UEFI mode. But best if both installs are in same boot mode or both UEFI or both BIOS. UEFI and BIOS are not really compatible, once you start booting you cannot change. Or grub can only offer to boot other systems in same boot mode. And if BIOS you only have one MBR per drive, and may want different boot loaders in each drive.

Comment: Both are in UEFI boot mode

Comment: I'd recommend a complete disk backup using Clonezilla, a free program.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is downsize your Windows on the SSD by 100 GB. Install Linux on that 100 GB free space (EXT4). The SSD is a lot faster than the HDD. And put your `/home-partition` (EXT4) on the HDD. Let's say 100 GB. The rest of the HDD as NTFS, for your documents, downloads, pictures, music and videos (etc). You can configure this in Windows and Ubuntu. 
Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS, but Windows can NOT read and write to EXT4 without third-party software. 
ps. I could not get this (free) software to work in Windows 10 though. This is how I would configure things if it was my system. I always seperate my doc's etc from my OS.